# Getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" sporadically

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, asynchronous

I'm trying to get data from a url and adding it to an array, then looping inside the pushed data and again calling the url and pushing the fetched data to the "data" property of the array element (and so on and so forth). It works most of the time but sometimes I get an error that "Cannot read property "push" of undefined randomly at "secondelement.data.push" or "thirdelement.data.push" or "fourthelement.data.push". I am trying to figure out what the error is but it fails randomly ever so often. Any help as to what the problem might be ?

```
firstHeadingArray = []
request.get(config.url.sectionMaster + "?parentSectionCode=" + sectionCode, function (err1, firstresult) {
        if (err1) { return next(err1) }
        if (firstresult != undefined) {
            // console.log("---------------------------FIRST------------------------")
            // console.log(JSON.parse(firstresult.body))
            firstresult = JSON.parse(firstresult.body).data
            if (firstresult != null) {
                firstresult.forEach(function (firstelement) {
                    firstHeadingArray.push({
                        "entityId": entityId,
                        "finYear": finYear,
                        "sectionCodeHead": sectionCode,
                        "unit": unit,
                        "sectionCodeDet": firstelement.sectionCode,
                        "sectionName": firstelement.sectionName,
                        "asOfDate": "",
                        "childAmount": "0.00",
                        "parentAmount": "0.00",
                        "manualEntry": 0,
                        "dispOrder": firstelement.dispOrder,
                        "AppStatus": "",
                        "Status": "",
                        "WF_SERIALNUMBER": "",
                        "WF_ACTION": "",
                        "leafNode": "",
                        "data": []
                    })
                })
                async.forEachSeries(firstHeadingArray, function (secondelement, scallback) {
                    // console.log(secondelement.sectionCodeDet)
                    request.get(config.url.sectionMaster + "?parentSectionCode=" + secondelement.sectionCodeDet, function (srerr, secondresult) {
                        if (srerr) { return next(srerr) }
                        // console.log("-----------------------------------SECOND--------------------------------")
                        // console.log(JSON.parse(secondresult.body))
                        if (secondresult != undefined) {
                            // console.log(secondresult)
                            secondresult = JSON.parse(secondresult.body).data
                            if (secondresult != null) {
                                secondresult.forEach(function (secelement) {
                                    secondelement.data.push({
                                        "entityId": entityId,
                                        "finYear": finYear,
                                        "sectionCodeHead": sectionCode,
                                        "unit": unit,
                                        "sectionCodeDet": secelement.sectionCode,
                                        "sectionName": secelement.sectionName,
                                        "asOfDate": "",
                                        "childAmount": "0.00",
                                        "parentAmount": "0.00",
                                        "manualEntry": 0,
                                        "dispOrder": secelement.dispOrder,
                                        "AppStatus": "",
                                        "Status": "",
                                        "WF_SERIALNUMBER": "",
                                        "WF_ACTION": "",
                                        "leafNode": "",
                                        "data": []
                                    })
                                })

                                // console.log(secondelement)
                                async.forEachSeries(secondelement.data, function (thirdelement, tcallback) {
                                    // console.log("here")
                                    // console.log(thirdelement.sectionCodeDet)
                                    request.get(config.url.sectionMaster + "?parentSectionCode=" + thirdelement.sectionCodeDet, function (trerr, thirdresult) {
                                        // console.log("-----------------------------------------THIRD--------------------------------------")
                                        // console.log(JSON.parse(thirdresult.body))
                                        if (trerr) { return next(trerr) }
                                        if (thirdresult != undefined) {
                                            thirdresult = JSON.parse(thirdresult.body).data
                                            if (thirdresult != null) {
                                                thirdresult.forEach(function (telement) {
                                                    thirdelement.data.push({
                                                        "entityId": entityId,
                                                        "finYear": finYear,
                                                        "sectionCodeHead": sectionCode,
                                                        "unit": unit,
                                                        "sectionCodeDet": telement.sectionCode,
                                                        "sectionName": telement.sectionName,
                                                        "asOfDate": "",
                                                        "childAmount": "0.00",
                                                        "parentAmount": "0.00",
                                                        "manualEntry": 0,
                                                        "dispOrder": telement.dispOrder,
                                                        "AppStatus": "",
                                                        "Status": "",
                                                        "WF_SERIALNUMBER": "",
                                                        "WF_ACTION": "",
                                                        "leafNode": "",
                                                        "data": []
                                                    })
                                                })
                                                // console.log(thirdresult)
                                                async.forEachSeries(thirdelement.data, function (fourthelement, fcallback) {
                                                    // console.log(fourthelement.sectionCodeDet)
                                                    request.get(config.url.sectionMaster + "?parentSectionCode=" + fourthelement.sectionCodeDet, function (frerr, fourthresult) {
                                                        // console.log("------------------------FOURTH---------------------")
                                                        // console.log(JSON.parse(fourthresult.body))
                                                        if (frerr) { return next(frerr) }
                                                        if (fourthresult != undefined) {
                                                            fourthresult = JSON.parse(fourthresult.body).data
                                                            if (fourthresult != null) {
                                                                fourthresult.forEach(function (felement) {
                                                                    fourthelement.data.push({
                                                                        "entityId": entityId,
                                                                        "finYear": finYear,
                                                                        "sectionCodeHead": sectionCode,
                                                                        "unit": unit,
                                                                        "sectionCodeDet": felement.sectionCode,
                                                                        "sectionName": felement.sectionName,
                                                                        "asOfDate": "",
                                                                        "childAmount": "0.00",
                                                                        "parentAmount": "0.00",
                                                                        "manualEntry": 0,
                                                                        "dispOrder": felement.dispOrder,
                                                                        "AppStatus": "",
                                                                        "Status": "",
                                                                        "WF_SERIALNUMBER": "",
                                                                        "WF_ACTION": "",
                                                                        "leafNode": "",
                                                                        "data": []
                                                                    })
                                                                })
                                                            }
                                                            fcallback()
                                                        } else {
                                                            res.send({ message: "Something went wrong, please try again." })
                                                            return;
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                }, function (ferr) {
                                                    // console.log("finished1")
                                                    if (ferr) { return next(ferr) }
                                                    tcallback()
                                                })
                                            } else { tcallback() }

                                        } else {
                                            res.send({ message: "Something went wrong, please try again." })
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    })
                                }, function (terr) {
                                    // console.log("finished2")
                                    if (terr) { return next(terr) }
                                    scallback()
                                })
                            } else { scallback() }
                        } else {
                            res.send({ message: "Something went wrong, please try again." })
                            return;
                        }
                    })
                },function(err){
                 res.send(firstHeadingArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got an error `Getting “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined” sporadically` due to `data` is `undefined` or not an `Array`

> Before `push` data in `array` just check its `exists` and `Array`.

```
if (secondelement.data && Array.isArray(secondelement.data)) {
  secondelement.data.push({
    "entityId": entityId,
    "finYear": finYear,
    "sectionCodeHead": sectionCode,
    "unit": unit,
    "sectionCodeDet": secelement.sectionCode,
    "sectionName": secelement.sectionName,
    "asOfDate": "",
    "childAmount": "0.00",
    "parentAmount": "0.00",
    "manualEntry": 0,
    "dispOrder": secelement.dispOrder,
    "AppStatus": "",
    "Status": "",
    "WF_SERIALNUMBER": "",
    "WF_ACTION": "",
    "leafNode": "",
    "data": []
  })
}
```

> Check same for `thirdelement.data` and `fourthelement.data`

Answer (score 0):

The reason to you problem is that , the data is not array that why it does not contain the push method in the data .

Check in that case if you got the secondelement.data , thirdelement.data as array or not , if not do what ever you want, make it array or don't push .

Check if the value is array .

New approach

```
Array.isArray(obj)
```

older approach

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]';
```